# Promise won't resolve in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, promise

Promise just won't resolve in unit test.

```
it('should break', function(done){
     const promise =  Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]); 
     promise.then(function(){
         expect(true).to.be.false;
         done();
     });
});
```

I have also tried this. (This is actually works in my seperate new sample project i created but this is not working in my real project so this is weird

import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('Hello function', function () {

```
it('should return hello world', function () {
    const promise = Promise.resolve(1);
    return promise.then(function () {
        expect(true).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

});

Background
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",

In karma.config.js

frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
 browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],

Error message i got

```
✖ should break
  HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6)
Error: Timeout of 9999ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Comment: As the error message says - you can either call `done()` or add `return` statement: `return promise.then ...`

Comment: @AlekseyL. i missed it i have already called done but it does not, work. using return also still not work though.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways to do asynchronous tests with mocha. Using `done()` or by returning a promise.

Because you're using promises, just returning the promise makes the most sense. This example removes `done` and returns the promise.

```
it('should break', function(){
  const promise =  Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]); 
  return promise.then(function(){
    expect(true).to.be.false();
  });
});
```

Rewritten as async/await + arrow functions:

```
it('should break', async () => {
  await [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5];
  expect(true).to.be.false();
});
```

Using `done()` *is* possible but you shouldn't mix returning promises and calling `done()`.

Comment: This does not works for me. this is so weird maybe there is some incorrect config in the project.

Comment: Then something else is broken, outside of your sample files

Comment: Thx for your help anyway. i have tried figuring it out whether it is karmar, webpack, etc...

Answer (score -1):

you have to return the promise and call done() after your assertion.

```
it('should break', function(done){
 const promise =  Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]); 
 return promise.then(function(){
     expect(true).to.be.false;
     done();
 });
});
```

Comment: No, you only have to do 1 of those two things. Return the Promise or call `done()`. Not both.